# Sleep OS X from Java

Tags: java, macos, sleep

Really simple little function, but does anyone know how to sleep OS X from Java?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

```
System.exec("osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to sleep'");
```

Answer (score 1):

See: [Making Mac OS X sleep from the command line](http://www.majid.info/mylos/weblog/2003/12/05-1.html)

Create a script with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript << EOT
tell application "System Events"
     sleep
end
EOT
```

And use system to exec it.

Answer (score -1):

```
    
public void gotoSleep(){
    try{
        logger.finer("Zzz...");

        if (preferences.getOS().equals("OSX") == true ){
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec
            ("/bin/bash");
        String command = "osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\"' " 
            + " -e \"sleep\" -e 'end tell'";

        OutputStream stdin = p.getOutputStream();
        stdin.write( command.getBytes() );
        stdin.flush();
        stdin.close();
        }

    }catch( Exception e ) { 
        logger.warning( e.toString() );
    }
}
```

For Some reason while i was doing it it did not work without executing it through bash.